# What are the greatest accomplishments of the United Nations?

Tags: united-nations

Looking back about 70 years now, what have been the greatest accomplishments of the United Nations? What use has the UN done?

Was the UN effective in ending the cold war peacefully?
Has the UN helped solve the conflicts centered on Israel and Korea, which seem to have occupied much of the UN's work during the last almost century. Was it for example productive during the Balkan wars in the 1990s? What function has the UN really fulfilled, when we objectively look back on its track record?

Even by asking the question, which seems to be a bit taboo, you understand that I'm not convinced of the usefulness of the UN. But I'm open minded and ask to learn about examples of its successes.

Comment: The Balkan war was eventually stopped. However,at the point where thousands of people have been brainwashed into doing ethnic cleansing, don't expect for peace appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: @user5751924 But really, when did the UN successfully negotiate a peace? It's main issues have been Israel and Korea, and there's no peace there. And the UN didn't do much to end the cold war, did it?

Comment: There are plenty of peacekeeping missions which do have some legitimacy thanks to the UN. Israël and Korea are only a fraction of what the UN spends its time on. In the last years, check Mali or Central Africa for instance. The UN is somehow powerless whenever a member of the permanent security council veto its actions, like for Israël or Korea.

Comment: ***Voting to re-open.***  I was in the middle of composing an answer.   And given the list of verifiable accomplishments, this doesn't seem all that opinion based to me.

Comment: This document seems to come from a legitimate university : http://www.pcr.uu.se/digitalAssets/64/c_64071-l_1-k_negotiating_peace.pdf

Comment: This question is poorly worded, and overly broad to fit into the SE format. There are expansive works extolling the accomplishments or failings of the UN.

Comment: Note that the UN also does a lot of efforts in order to guarantee refugees have a correct treatment, and is also concerned with issues like global health, hunger, education, poverty and climate change. If you want to specificly focus on peace treaties, you should narrow down your question.

Comment: http://www.un.org/en/sections/what-we-do/index.html

Comment: @user5751924 - the balcan war wasn't UN. It was NATO, and mainly, really, US bombing.

Comment: It only has one, assisting the creation of Israel.